# Prevent tableview from being reused (MVVM )

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, mvvm, uitableviewrowaction

I know how to preserve the action we have done on `UITableView`, after scrolling back and forth.

Now  Iam doing a simple `UITableView` on MVVM
which has a Follow button .[image: follow button]  like this.
Follow button changes to Unfollow after click and resets after scrolling.
Where and How to add the code to prevent this?

Here is the tableview Code

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return Vm.personFollowingTableViewViewModel.count
    
}
var selectedIndexArray:[Int] = []
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: FollowList_MVVM.PersonFollowingTableViewCell.identifier , for: indexPath) as? PersonFollowingTableViewCell else{
        return UITableViewCell()
    }


    cell.configure(with: Vm.personFollowingTableViewViewModel[indexPath.row])
    cell.delegate = self
    return cell
    
    
}
```

and `configure(with: )` function

```
@objc public func didTapButton(){
    let defaultPerson = Person(name: "default", username: "default", currentFollowing: true, image: nil)
    let currentFollowing = !(person?.currentFollowing ?? false)
    person?.currentFollowing = currentFollowing
    delegate?.PersonFollowingTableViewCell(self, didTapWith: person ?? defaultPerson )    
    configure(with: person ?? defaultPerson)
}


func configure(with person1 : Person){
    
    
    self.person = person1
    nameLabel.text = person1.name
    usernameLabel.text = person1.username
    userImageview.image = person1.image
    
    
    
    if person1.currentFollowing{
        //Code to change button UI
        
    }
```

custom delegate of type `Person` is used

Comment: If you are really using MVVM then your view model should hold your model objects (Person) and not your cells

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Could you please elaborate? in ViewModel I only have have some hardcoded data based on models

Comment: You need to at least tell the view model when you have updated a person, it is the view model that holds the data, not the cell. Your Person object in the cell should only be seen as a copy of the original data which resides, as mentioned, in the view model.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thanks. I have done more reference on this and updated with my own answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your main issue is with `Button` title getting changed on *scroll*, so i am posting a solution for that.

**Note-:** Below code doesn’t follow *MVVM*.

***Controller-:***

```
import UIKit

class TestController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var testTableView: UITableView!
    var model:[Model] = []
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        for i in 0..<70{
            let modelObject = Model(name: "A\(i)", "Follow")
            model.append(modelObject)
        }
    }
}

extension TestController:UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
        return model.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! TestTableCell
        cell.dataModel = model[indexPath.row]
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100
    }
    
}


extension TestController:Actions{
    func followButton(cell: UITableViewCell) {
        let indexPath = testTableView.indexPath(for: cell)
        model[indexPath!.row].buttonTitle = "Unfollow"
        testTableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .automatic)
    }
}

class Model{
    var name: String?
    var buttonTitle: String
    
    init(name: String?,_ buttonTitle:String) {
        self.name = name
        self.buttonTitle = buttonTitle
    }
}
```

**Cell-:**

```
import UIKit

protocol Actions:AnyObject{
    func followButton(cell:UITableViewCell)
}

class TestTableCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var followButtonLabel: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var eventLabel: UILabel!
    
    var dataModel:Model?{
        didSet{
            guard let model = dataModel else{
                return
            }
            
            followButtonLabel.setTitle(model.buttonTitle, for: .normal)
            eventLabel.text = model.name
        }
    }
    
    weak var delegate:Actions?
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }
    
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        
        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
    
    @IBAction func followAction(_ sender: Any) {
        delegate?.followButton(cell:self)
    }
}
```

To convert this into *MVVM* approach, there are few things you need to change and move out.

1. The loop I have in `viewDidLoad` shouldn’t be there. That will be some API call, and should be handled by *viewModel*, and *viewModel* can *delegate* that to other repository to handle or handle itself. Upon receiving response *viewModel* update its state and communicate with `View` (in our case `tableView`) to re-render itself.
2. Code in `extension` where I am updating model object shouldn’t be in controller  `(model[indexPath!.row].buttonTitle = "Unfollow")`, that has to be done by *viewModel*, and once the *viewModel* state changes it should communicate with view to re-render.
3. The interaction responder (Button action) in `Cell` class, should delegate action to *viewModel* and not `controller`.
4. `Model` class should be in its own separate file.

In short *viewModel* handles the `State` of your `View` and it should be the one watching your `model` for updates, and upon change it should ask *View* to re-render.

There are more things you could do to follow strict *MVVM* approach and make your code more loosely coupled and testable. Above points might not be 100% correct I have just shared some basic ideas i have. You can check article online for further follow up.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer works . But I have gone through what suggested by @Joakim Danielson to find what exactly happens when you are updating the `View` and Why it is not updating on `ViewModel`

So I made an update to delegate function

1. `ViewController` delegate function

   `func PersonFollowingTableViewCell1( _ cell: PersonFollowingTableViewCell, array  : Person, tag : Int)`

Here, I called the array in the `Viewmodel` and assigned the values of `array` in `func` argument to it.

like `ViewModel().Vmarray[tag].currentFollow = array[tag].currentFollow`